# What is the most primitive possible toolchain for android programming?

Tags: android, toolchain

I feel as though I'm trying to learn android programming in the middle of a fireworks display during a rodeo. All the fancy IDE stuff recommended by all the books I seem to find is just monumentally distracting from discovering what I really and truly need just to develop an android app.

Can anyone point me at documentation for the minimal set of the tools needed to actually build an app? I feel like if I could understand what the heck was actually going on, I'd be better able to use the fancy IDE.

Comment: I second @WarrenFaith. Whatever he has suggested is the bare minimum you'll need to develop an Android app.

Comment: If you want you can substitute eclipse with the command line and a text editor for editing java/xml. See [Managing projects from the command line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and [Building and running from the command line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html). All you need is (as already mentioned) a java 6 install, the android sdk, a terminal and an editor of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive?  So, not Eclipse, and also not ant.  You can use aapt, javac, dx, apkbuilder, and signer directly.  Or more-or-less directly; you're still a programmer, you have ways of dealing with repetition.

I do some on-device app development with [Terminal IDE](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/).  This is one my build scripts (named 'make'):

```
P=me/rapacity/stitch

rm src/$P/R.java
mkdir -m 770 -p dist || exit
mkdir -m 770 -p build/classes || exit
mkdir -m 770 -p tmp || exit

./index.perl

aapt p -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -F build/resources.res \
     -I ~/sdk/3.2/android.jar -S res/ -J src/$P || exit

cd src
for F in \
    SelectActivity.java Tilesets.java \
        StitchActivity.java \
        TilesetView.java \
; do
  if test $P/$F -nt ../build/classes/$P/$(dirname $F)/$(basename $F .java).class; then
    echo Building $P/$F
    REBUILD=1
    javac -d ../build/classes $P/$F 2> ../tmp/javac.out
    ../redcat ../tmp/javac.out
    grep error ../tmp/javac.out && exit
  fi
done
cd ..

if [ ! -z $REBUILD ]; then
  set -x
  ( cd src; javac -d ../build/classes $P/R.java )
  ( cd build/classes; dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=../core.dex me ) ||  # 'me' as in me.rapacity.

  apkbuilder dist/core.apk -u -z build/resources.res -f build/core.dex || exit
  signer dist/core.apk core-debug.apk
else
  echo +++ No need to rebuild .apk
fi
```

in which some lengths are gone to to avoid recompilation and to promptly exit after an error. Very little of that needs to be edited per-project.

Comment: Excellent! That is the sort of low level info I've been looking for.

Comment: Have fun modifying this with "beginners knowledge". And this is in no way simpler than pressing `ctrl + F11` in eclipse! +1 though for sharing the script.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, beginners knowledge of unix?  Then this is useless.  Beginner's knowledge of Android?  Then this is perhaps more useful.  Beginner's knowledge of Java?  If you don't understand the appeal of the question... here's a short story: I used Emacs daily.  Someone in #perl pasted a link and asked if anyone could read it and explain WTF it was trying to communicate.  I read it.  I could explain nothing.  It was http://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: I believe that this script does not handle the inclusion of jars and definitely not full blown library projects. This still answers the question, but is not a replacement for existing build systems (ant/eclipse).

Comment: @CoatedMoose, Terminal IDE comes with library examples. The chief advantage of this script is that it can be run on an Android device.

Comment: My comment was merely observing that this particular script doesn't handle library dependencies. I have been using Terminal IDE for some things (git, vim, file transfer), but haven't really investigated its full android build experience. (I have been using AIDE for building lately.)

Answer (score 2):

1. [Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (NOT Java7!)
2. Recommended IDE is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (recommended as there are guides for it on the official documentation)
3. Android SDK (you need to download the API you want to develop for) and ADT - the android development tools - [Guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Optional:

1. Device and a connection for it, recommended, not necessary as an Emulator is bundled in the Android SDK

Comment: I don't think I'd call Eclipse minimal. I'd call it the source of most of the fireworks and bucking broncos :-).

Comment: Without eclipse you need a way to build, deploy and run your app. That can be done by ant or maven but since you should work with a tool that helps you eliminating a lot of beginner failures, you should consider a real IDE. Eclipse is way more powerful than you will ever see while developing for android but it is the easiest and therefore primitiviest possible solution for the above mentioned tasks.

Comment: I'm afraid this beginner's brain doesn't work that way. All I see is the possibility of spending weeks fighting with Eclipse and such only to discover my problem had nothing to do with actual android programming. I'd much rather make mistakes directly related to android, those I can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Give [AIDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aide.ui) a try for Android on-device App development. It is very easy to get started and the project format is fully compatible with Eclipse, so if you want to continue development on your PC you can.

Getting started video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=NGT9MqT3W2w